# Using "$" in Oracle queries being run from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g

I want to run an Oracle query which is somewhat like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM v$sql 
 WHERE ......
```

But when I use "v$sql" in C#, I am getting an error "Invalid character".

When I remove that part of the query and replace it with some other table name, it is running fine.

Comment: Which connector do you use ? The microsoft one or the oracle one ?

Comment: When are you getting that error? Compiling your code or executing it? What is the full error message? is it .Net or Oracle that throws that error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with C# but try putting v$sql in double quotes: `"V$SQL"`

Double quotes makes Oracle case sensitive so it needs to be uppercase.

Or try a synonym:

`create synonym  my_v_sql for sys.V_$SQL;
or 
create public synonym  my_v_sql for sys.V_$SQL;`

Comment: I am getting that error from Oracle. Something like "ORA-09011 Invalid character". Dont remember the exact code. 
No compilation problems. 
Problem is that is a production DB so access is limited. So cant change anything from DB side. Whatever we got to do, we need to do it from C#.

Comment: Is there a space before the $? There shouldn't be, of course. Did you try the double quotes? Is c# or .net altering the query text before it's sent to Oracle?